# scrapy not following links

Tags: python, scrapy

The following scrapy code for returning medical treatment information does return the first set of returned results, but does not follow links. Learning code and checked similar results here on stackoverflow, but integrating them did not work. True, I'm learning. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
import urlparse

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
import w3lib.url

from yelp.items import YelpItem


class YelpSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "yelp"
    download_delay = 10
    concurrent_requests = 1
    concurrent_requests_per_domain = 1
    allowed_domains = ["yelp.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=cancer+treatment&find_loc=manhattan%2Cny&start=0",
"http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=cancer+treatment&find_loc=manhattan%2Cny&start=20",
"http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=cancer+treatment&find_loc=manhattan%2Cny&start=30"]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        for title in selector.css("span.indexed-biz-name"):
            page_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url,
                                        title.xpath("a/@href").extract()[0])
            self.log("page URL: %s" % page_url)
            #continue
            yield Request(page_url,
                          callback=self.parse_page)

        for next_page in selector.css(u'ul > li > a.prev-next:contains(\u2192)'):
            next_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url,
                                        next_page.xpath('@href').extract()[0])
            self.log("next URL: %s" % next_url)
            #continue
            yield Request(next_url,
                          callback=self.parse)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        item = YelpItem()
        item["name"] = selector.xpath('.//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item["addresslocality"] = u"\n".join(
            selector.xpath('.//address[@itemprop="address"]//text()').extract()).strip()
        item["link"] = response.url
        website = selector.css('div.biz-website a')
        if website:
            website_url = website.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            item["website"] = w3lib.url.url_query_parameter(website_url, "url")
        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Your next URL extraction and selection logic is not correct. Target the link element having `next` and `pagination-links_anchor` classes. The following works for me:

```
next_url = response.css('a.pagination-links_anchor.next::attr(href)').extract_first()
if next_url:
    next_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, next_url)
    self.log("next URL: %s" % next_url)
    yield Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: this partially solves the issues. I now notice that all the start_urls URLs are first being collected, then the analysis begins of each individual URL. Ideally this is supposed to collect the first 10 URLs, conduct the analysis (dig deeper into the links), then proceed to the next start_url listed.

Comment: @jeffschips I would say that's a different follow-up issue - please consider creating a separate topic for that if you experience difficulties. Thanks.